# neon effect to textures libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I am working on a live wallpaper with Libgdx . 
I am wondering if I can give neon glow to my textures , at runtime . 
Is this possible? If yes can anybody give me any pointers?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site. This site is for questions that are more like "well I tried this and got stuck here, how do I fix it?" -- your question will (sadly) probably be closed.

Comment: There's nothing particularly "libgdx-specific" about this question; glow effects can be implemented in basically the same way across many engines/platforms. Tweaking the result to be more like a neon sign versus a glowing fireball is primarily down to tweaking the art asset representing the glow's blur.

Comment: There's a lot of [related questions](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=glow) here already, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, sure. Two approaches come to mind:

1. Write a shader
2. Fake it

For faking it, you could draw four copies of the sprite (offsetting horizontally and vertically by 1px above/below/right/left of the main image) and tinting that to your neon colour.

I haven't tried it, so your mileage may vary.